# How to use proxy in LWR, to forward all api calls to external api server (express)

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have installed LWR and listening on port 4000  and created small LWC component and wanted to redirect all my fetch requests to api server (listening on port 3000).

When I configured package.json with "proxy" : "http://localhost:3000", fetch requests are not going to 3000 port but it's going to 4000, which requires to enable CORS which I don't want.

Comment: App.use resolve function in server.js file? Can you post package.json script?

Answer (score 0):

In development the quick and easy fix is indeed to enable cors.

When running in production you should use some router (like nginx) in order to route all requests coming in at `/api` (or some other endpoint) to be routed to your backend service.